# Bootstrap : clearfix doesn't work and same height with multiple rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

(Sorry for my bad english)

I'm trying to do a team page on Boostrap. I've 2 problems.

Here is the **Bootply**: http://www.bootply.com/xkMGZqW9hh

1) I wanted to do the same height for elements. I tried those 3 solutions : [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height) and this : https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height but none of them worked well... negative margin doesn't allow to put border on bottom and I need it :/ and the others solutions put all the elements in only one row!

2) On my local project the floating elements are... weird. But on Bootply it works fine! I don't understand... I copied and pasted my code O_O
I'm trying to center the elements in "Admin" and align the elements of the second line to the left... But I don't know how many elements I'll have ;) (MySQL)

This is a screen of my problem :
[image: floating problem]

I really don't understand why on Bootply it works "fine" but the centered...

What I'm trying to do :

[image: result expected]

Thank you <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. As FrontMonkey said I used flex to align columns but I had to add some options.

**Bootply** http://www.bootply.com/bUHfF33c59

Answer (score 0):

Use css3 flex to align columns.
http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Comment: Already tried as I said but it doesn't respect the responsive... It put all the elements in only one row.
Exemple : http://www.bootply.com/hkoyiq2hHb